# How to load a JSON string from an external URL onto a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome Extension development, so please help me with it.

I'm trying to read a JSON String from this URL
http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?Subcategory=16&SortType=3&ResultsPerPage=10

And I want to display the result on a HTML Table on the **browser_action.html *popup*.**

I know this a very generic question, but it would help me if you could guide me.

Comment: It's not a _generic_ question, it's a _broad_ question. It might be better if you split it in two, since there are 2 separate issues here (getting the data, and displaying it as a table).

Comment: both q are duplicates  covered by existing questions. dup but km lazy to search them.

Comment: alright, so how do I get data? any tutorials? I did search, but no luck

Comment: Use $.getJSON(url,data,success(data,status,xhr))

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll want to read up on [cross-domain XHR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) to fetch the JSON from roblox.com and [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) to show a browser action popup. Please open a new question if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little browsing, I found a step-by step guide on [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp)

I used this tool to create the template : [Extensionizr](http://extensionizr.com/!#%7B%22modules%22:[%22browser-mode%22,%22with-bg%22,%22with-persistent-bg%22,%22no-options%22,%22no-override%22],%22boolean_perms%22:[],%22match_ptrns%22:[]%7D)

And I just added a Popup.js into the same folder as browser_action.html

**Inside Popup.js :**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + 
    arr[i].Name +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].City +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Country +
    "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>";
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

**Inside browser_action.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>
<script src=popup.js></script>

<div id="mainPopup">

<div id="id01"></div>
```

And that's it :)

Comment: Well, can't fault you for actually compiling an answer afterwards, despite the question being poorly received! Have your upvote.